# Redirection to unwanted links on all browsers

Tags: macos, redirect

I keep on getting redirected to unwanted websites or link mostly to mackeeper and keep on getting alerts thats my mac is not secured.

This is extremely annoying.

Comment: Sounds like you have malware installed.

Comment: Yes, deleted all content related to that, I am not facing any issues now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could follow the below link

https://support.norton.com/sp/en/us/home/current/solutions/v102043536_EndUserProfile_en_us

Happy browsing.